# In android, How do i save response coming from php login script as shared preference?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, session-management

i have seen most of the examples of offline apps , but what should i do if my response comes from php api ? Basically my app logins and give request to an api , and i get a response. Suppose i get reponse as email and a token. So how should i use it in session management? so that user don't have to login all the time when he exits app.

Comment: you can use sharedprefences for save email and token. if you want to know how to do, search in Google that you find what you need

Comment: Do you have already the body of the response as String object?

Comment: @Roran yes i am taking the response and storing it in string variables,infact i am using it in welcome screen , but what i want is to use those response in maintaining session.

Answer (score 0):

**you can store email and token in shared prefrence like this**

**when user succefully login store data in sharedpreferences like this**

```
public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;
public static final String email = "email";
public static final String token = "token";
public static final boolean isLogin = "islogin";

SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

// store login data in sharedpreferences
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putString(email, "rathodnilsrk@gmail.com");
editor.putString(token, "123456789");
editor.putBoolean(isLogin, true);
editor.commit(); //save data in  sharedpreferences
```

**now  when your application start that check that user is login or not like this**

```
public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


// get boolean from sharedprefrence 
public static final boolean isLogin = "islogin";
boolean login = prefs.getBoolean(isLogin, false);

// check login status
if(login){ 
    // user session available move to home screen
}else{
// user does not login move to login screen
}
```

Comment: Thank you i will try this. :)

Comment: and for logout button i have to clear and commit editor and jump to login activity again right ?

Comment: and btw can i put the string variable in value part of like editor.putString(email,email); ? rather than directly giving value as rathodnil@gmail.com as you have given ? becoz my values will change as per the users (thats quite obvious).