# How do i use SharedPreferences to store user email and password

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

Just saying, im new at android proggaming, what i wanna do it's just store the email and pass if the user check the check "checarSessao" CheckBox, and stay logged, if he closes the app, when he opens again, i wanna show the Home automatically instead of login screen again...

Here is my Login

```
package complete.lyne.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText loginEmail, loginSenha;
Button btLogar;
TextView refCadastrar;

String url = "";
String parametro = "";

private Session session;
private CheckBox checkBox;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);

    loginEmail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.loginEmail);
    loginSenha = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.loginSenha);
    btLogar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btLogar);
    refCadastrar = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.refCadastrar);
    checkBox = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checarSessao);

    refCadastrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent abreCadastro = new Intent(Login.this, Cadastro.class);
            startActivity(abreCadastro);
        }
    });

    checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checarSessao);
    if (!new Session(this).Logado()) {
        //user's email and password both are saved in preferences
        startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, Home.class));
    }


    btLogar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)
                    getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

            if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {

                String email = loginEmail.getText().toString();
                String senha = loginSenha.getText().toString();

                if(email.isEmpty() && senha.matches(".*[a-z].*")) {
                    loginEmail.setError("Insira seu endereço de Email.");
                } else if (email.matches(".*[a-z].*") && senha.isEmpty()) {
                    loginSenha.setError("Insira sua Senha.");
                } else if (email.isEmpty() && senha.isEmpty()) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nenhum campo pode ficar vazio.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {

                    // Casa
                    url = "http://192.168.1.103/lyne/logar.php";

                    // Badran
                    // url = "http://172.16.2.15/lyne/logar.php";

                    parametro = "email=" + email + "&senha=" + senha;

                    new SolicitaDados().execute(url);

                }

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nenhuma conexão com a Internet foi encontrada.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }


        }
    });
    }

private class SolicitaDados extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            return Conexao.postDados(urls[0], parametro);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String resultado) {

       if(resultado != null) {
            if (resultado.contains("login_ok")) {

                String[] dados = resultado.split(",");

                Intent abreHome = new Intent(Login.this, Home.class);

                abreHome.putExtra("idusu", dados[0]);
                abreHome.putExtra("nomeusu", dados[1]);
                abreHome.putExtra("sobreusu", dados[2]);
                abreHome.putExtra("emailusu", dados[3]);
                abreHome.putExtra("senhausu", dados[4]);

                String email = loginEmail.getText().toString();
                String password = loginSenha.getText().toString();

                if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
                    salvarLogin(email, password);
                    startActivity(abreHome);
                    finish();
                }

                overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_out, android.R.anim.fade_in);

                startActivity(abreHome);
                finish();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Usuário ou senha incorretos.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

}

private void salvarLogin(String email, String password) {
    new Session(this).salvarLogin(email, password);
}

}
```

Here is my Session

```
package complete.lyne.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

/**
* Created by Higor on 10/08/2017.
*/

public class Session {

Context context;

Session(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

public void salvarLogin(String email, String senha) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("LoginDetails", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("Email", email);
    editor.putString("Senha", senha);
    editor.commit();
}

public String getEmail() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("LoginDetails", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sharedPreferences.getString("Email", "");
}

public boolean Logado() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("LoginDetails", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean isEmailEmpty = sharedPreferences.getString("Email", "").isEmpty();
    boolean isPasswordEmpty = sharedPreferences.getString("Password", "").isEmpty();
    return isEmailEmpty || isPasswordEmpty;
}
}
```

And my Home

```
package complete.lyne.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import static complete.lyne.myapplication.R.layout.header_navegacao;

public class Home extends AppCompatActivity {


// Fragmentos

FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
NavigationView navigationView;

// Fim dos Fragmentos

TextView bdNome;
String uNome;

private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle aToggle;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home);
    Home.this.overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);

    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.DrawerLayout);
    aToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.abrir, R.string.fechar);

    navigationView = (NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
    View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    bdNome = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.bdNome);
    uNome = getIntent().getExtras().getString("nomeusu");
    bdNome.setText(uNome);

    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(aToggle);
    aToggle.syncState();

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    // Fragmentos

    fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_container,new HomeFragment());
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Line");
    navigationView = (NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {

                case R.id.mConta:
                    fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container,new ContaFragment());
                    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("tag");
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Minha Conta");
                    item.setChecked(true);
                    drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    break;

                case R.id.mPerfil:
                    fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container,new PerfilFragment());
                    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("tag");
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Perfil");
                    item.setChecked(true);
                    drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    break;

                case R.id.mAmigos:
                    fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container,new AmigosFragment());
                    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("tag");
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Amigos");
                    item.setChecked(true);
                    drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    break;

                case R.id.mSobre:
                    fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container,new SobreFragment());
                    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("tag");
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Sobre");
                    item.setChecked(true);
                    drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    break;

                case R.id.mSair:
                    fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container,new SobreFragment());
                    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("tag");
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    item.setChecked(true);
                    drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    break;

            }

            return true;
        }
    });

    // Fim Fragmentos

}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if(aToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout layout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.DrawerLayout);
    Home.this.overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
    if (layout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

}
```

SOLUTION

Login

```
package complete.lyne.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText loginEmail, loginSenha;
Button btLogar;
TextView refCadastrar;

String url = "";
String parametro = "";

private CheckBox checkBox;

public static final String info_usuario = "info_usuario";
public static final String email = "email";
public static final String senha = "senha";
public static final String nomeusu = "nomeusu";
public static final boolean isLogin = Boolean.parseBoolean("islogin");

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);

    loginEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginEmail);
    loginSenha = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginSenha);
    btLogar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btLogar);
    refCadastrar = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.refCadastrar);
    checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checarSessao);

    SharedPreferences sharedPref;
    sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("info_usuario", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean login = sharedPref.getBoolean(String.valueOf(isLogin), false);

    if(login){
        Intent abreHome = new Intent(Login.this, Home.class);
        startActivity(abreHome);
    }


    refCadastrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent abreCadastro = new Intent(Login.this, Cadastro.class);
            startActivity(abreCadastro);
        }
    });

    btLogar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)
                    getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

            if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {

                String email = loginEmail.getText().toString();
                String senha = loginSenha.getText().toString();

                if (email.isEmpty() && senha.matches(".*[a-z].*")) {
                    loginEmail.setError("Insira seu endereço de Email.");
                } else if (email.matches(".*[a-z].*") && senha.isEmpty()) {
                    loginSenha.setError("Insira sua Senha.");
                } else if (email.isEmpty() && senha.isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nenhum campo pode ficar vazio.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {

                    // Casa
                    url = "http://192.168.1.103/lyne/logar.php";

                    // Badran
                    // url = "http://172.16.2.15/lyne/logar.php";

                    parametro = "email=" + email + "&senha=" + senha;

                    new SolicitaDados().execute(url);

                }

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nenhuma conexão com a Internet foi encontrada.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }


        }
    });
}

private class SolicitaDados extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        return Conexao.postDados(urls[0], parametro);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String resultado) {

        if (resultado != null) {
            if (resultado.contains("login_ok")) {

                String[] dados = resultado.split(",");

                Intent abreHome = new Intent(Login.this, Home.class);

                abreHome.putExtra("idusu", dados[0]);
                abreHome.putExtra("nomeusu", dados[1]);
                abreHome.putExtra("sobreusu", dados[2]);
                abreHome.putExtra("emailusu", dados[3]);
                abreHome.putExtra("senhausu", dados[4]);

                if (checkBox.isChecked()) {

                    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("info_usuario", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                    editor.putString(email, loginEmail.getText().toString());
                    editor.putString(senha, loginSenha.getText().toString());
                    editor.putString(nomeusu, "Higor");
                    editor.putBoolean(String.valueOf(isLogin), true);
                    editor.commit();
                    editor.apply();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Esta marcado.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    startActivity(abreHome);
                    finish();

                }

                overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_out, android.R.anim.fade_in);

                startActivity(abreHome);
                finish();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Usuário ou senha incorretos.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

}

public class Global extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        String recentSearches = sharedPreferences.getString("email", "");

        if (recentSearches.isEmpty()) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Shared preferences example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example)

Comment: check this ans it may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45168556/in-android-how-do-i-save-response-coming-from-php-login-script-as-shared-prefer/45168962#45168962

Answer (score 0):

Use below code;

For storing values;

```
 SharedPreferences sp=getSharedPreferences("Login", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 SharedPreferences.Editor Ed=sp.edit();
 Ed.putString("id",login_id.getText().toString() );
 Ed.putString("password",login_password.getText().toString() );
 Ed.commit();
```

For getting values;

```
  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("Login", MODE_PRIVATE);
  String uName = sharedPreferences.getString("id", "");
  String password = sharedPreferences.getString("password", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code is working for me. try this.

to store value in preferences

```
 SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
 editor.putString("email",Email);
 editor.putString("password",Password);
 editor.commit();
 editor.apply();
```

to get value from preferences

```
 SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
 String email = preferences.getString("email", "");
 String pass = preferences.getString("password", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check it, only for the first time per application start is better to make general class.
you can do that like this: (this class run once per application start)

```
public class Global extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    String email = sharedPreferences.getString("email", "");

    if(email.isEmpty()){
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YOUR_ACTIVITY.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

And then you should register the class in Manifest:

```
<application 
    android:name=".Global" 

    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name="MyActivity"
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: i tried that way but doenst works here, i already fix the problem! Thank you for helping me.

Comment: if you fix the problem, Add it as answer, maybe it can help another person.